# Does PHP have a data type bigger than int?

Tags: php

I want to save a 11 digit number inside a variable. How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 64-bit version of PHP uses 64-bit integers natively, so that's plenty of bits for an 11-digit number. That said, if you need larger integers, I would use the [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension.

Comment: @Jack says he only wants to save an 11 digit number. Handling it as a string may be a lot less of an overhead.

Comment: @symcbean: True, but if he wants to do math on that integer, he'll want a library like BC Math. I guess I made an assumption before answering, but I figured he wanted to do more than just store it in a variable.

Answer (score 4):

The [GMP](https://www.php.net/gmp) library is also worth looking at.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, mediumint and bigint is there.

Comment: I don't know what you were referring to, but PHP does not support integers larger than 32 bits on 32-bit platforms. -1